# What is this type of lead called and how do I wire to it correctly?

Tags: electrical, wiring

I'm becoming more frustrated than I'd like to admit trying to wire this button up,
  and I often find the easier method it was designed for when I'm having this much trouble.

Sorry for the poor man's macro; there is a clickthrough to the product's datasheet.

If this question is off-topic for DIY.SE and on-topic for another, by all means flag for migration.  I'm following a past suggestion from [this question](https://electronics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/688) over at EE.SE.

[image: …]

Comment: It should go without saying that I'm asking this *before* I solder the wires onto the leads.

Comment: I don't understand what the question is.  The type of leads are called solder terminals or solder lugs.  Is there a diagram showing how the leads are connected as the button is operated?  That should show the proper way to connect to it for your needs.

Comment: @wallyk No, no diagram unfortunately—no documentation whatsoever save the datasheet—but that did give me an idea. Do you think these are mean to be through-holes of sorts? Where I would stick in the wire and then fill the hole with solder?

Comment: The photo is showing a wire correctly threaded through.  To make it reliable, just solder in place, like [this](http://ramoem.com/images/solder-joints.jpg) or [that](http://2.bp.blogspot.com/-UprgsBs1z60/UVIXnnVU_NI/AAAAAAAABGg/Uji1Y9XpUu8/s1600/solder1.JPG).

Comment: @wallyk Yes it is threaded through, but wrapping it around like that was a short-circuit waiting to happen—it is incredibly bulky in person. I'm going to see where I can get with the through-hole soldering idea and post a CW answer if another doesn't turn up.

Comment: I'm not sure the EE people understand the definitions of "home" in home improvement and "hobby" in hobby projects.

Comment: @BMitch this is certainly a hobbyist project, but I'd somewhat agree it's not quite 'home' improvement (in spite of the many home improvement applications).

Comment: @SeanAllred I mentioned "hobby project" because they are explicitly considered off topic. The times I've seen the community override that is when the procedure can apply to other home improvement tasks. So someone might be asking how to solder a pipe for a hobby project, but the technique would also work for a plumbing project.

Comment: @BMitch Feel free to close/migrate; as I said—I wasn't sure this was the place for the question in the first place.

Comment: @SeanAllred it's in a gray area, but others from the community don't seem to have a problem with it, so no mod hammer from me. I did want to be sure that others looking at this question didn't use it as an example of a good on topic question.

Comment: @BMitch What will probably happen, is at some point in the future it will get closed when the community on this site gets big enough.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Making connections

You can use [heatshrink tubing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heat-shrink_tubing) to insulate the connection and prevent the wires shorting together.

[image]

Slide a section on, out of the way, before attaching the wire, solder the wire, slide the tube over the exposed wire and heat it to shrink it.

### Which connections

You don't say what this "button" is for. I don't know of a function for a push-button operating a switch with five terminals.

You can usually use the continuity function of a multimeter to work out which terminals are connected to which before, whilst and after pressing the button. From this you can work out  how to wire up the connections to whatever it controls.

Comment: If you were curious, it's a SPDT momentary with an integrated LED, and it will be mounted into an enclosure to control on/off.  Thanks for the heatshrink reminder—I definitely would have forgotten that!

Comment: FYI, they are called Solder lugs

Answer (score 2):

You might be able to use an appropriately sized female disconnect crimp terminal.

[image: Female Disconnect]

Simply insert the wire into the insulated (blue) end, crimp the wire into a female disconnect using a crimping tool, then fit the terminal onto the appropriate pin.

Fully insulated, and fully insulated 90 degree female disconnects are also available.

[image: Fully insulated female disconnect][image: Fully insulated 90 degree female disconnect]

Comment: It appears that this [might fit it](http://www.parts-express.com/110-(16-14)-female-disconnect-crimp-terminal-blue-50-pcs--095-286) (.110").  Are you suggesting putting the blue end down onto the button, or the other way around?

Comment: You insert the wire into the blue (insulated) end and crimp the connector onto the wire. The uninsulated end would go onto the connector on the switch.

Comment: Those are not crimp terminals and not structural suited for it.